# Getting rid of weird behaviour with custom ng mouse enter/leave

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I have this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zCWzbvdY2wr5Oe0AqTdJ?p=preview), this logic controls the buttons showing and hiding:

```
$scope.change = function (over) {
  if (over) {
    $timeout(function () {
      $scope.changed = over;  
    }, 1020);  
  } else {
    $scope.changed = over;
  }
}

$scope.changed = false;
```

The `$timeout` exists to make sure the buttons only show once the animation is done.

If you move you mouse very quickly in and out of the bar marked "-- hover .... --" you'll see it start to perform weird behaviour - i.e. the buttons never hiding when the bar is "minimised".

Debouncing would be a good solution, but the whole function can't be debounced because then the behaviour starts to go crazy.

Throttling the whole function works better than debouncing but the problem still exists.

I'm starting to think complicated about the solution, but does anyone already know of a way to do this?

Comment: can you be more descriptive of weirdness? is it just the add/delete showing up outside of the container?

Comment: Yeah, if you do it slowly,  then everything works nicely, the buttons show up after the animation and then disappear when the mouse leaves. However if you do it really quickly the buttons sometimes never disappear. @pherris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you've accepted the answer already, but this approach seems unnecessarily complex and to me, the user experience is a bit startling (scrolling an area into view and then flashing content into that area).

An alternative is to just hide the content that is not visible in your div by adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.removeBar` and removing a bunch of JS: http://plnkr.co/edit/XZHhIKUx5LQpclp8QoAC?p=preview

This saves you complexity, maintainability and testing etc (and possibly helps your page load faster by removing some libraries).

Comment: That is also very genius that is what I was going for in the first place.... thanks!!

Comment: Great. Thanks.. This solution is much better.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cancel the timeouts that are created, using `$timeout.cancel`

```
$scope.change = function (over) {
  $timeout.cancel($scope.timeInterval);
  if (over) {
    $scope.timeInterval = $timeout(function () {
      $scope.changed = over;  
    }, 1020);  
  } else {
    $scope.changed = over;
  }
}
```

Here is the updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/EgK9ggqKpEEuz9w3yl1y?p=preview